# Why does Emscripten not "find the file specified"?

Tags: windows, sdk, emscripten

As far as I can tell, I have installed all the dependencies with the Emscripten SDK but when I run the "Emscripten command prompt" I get the following output:

```
    Adding directories to PATH:
    PATH += C:\Program Files\Emscripten\spidermonkey\30.0.0_64bit
    PATH += C:\Program Files\Emscripten\git\1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\gi
    t\1.9.4\cmd

    The system cannot find the file specified.

    C:\Program Files\Emscripten>
```

Furthermore, when I try to compile a library, I get the following:

```
    C:\Alice-master\deps\snappy-1.1.1>emconfigure configure
    ERROR    root: Exception thrown when invoking Popen in configure with args: "con
    figure"!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.27.0\\emconfigure", line 24, in
     
        shared.Building.configure(sys.argv[1:])
      File "C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.27.0\tools\shared.py", line 108
    4, in configure
        process = Popen(args, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=env)
      File "C:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", lin
    e 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "C:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", lin
    e 948, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried it in different directories. If I try the other command that I read in the package's explanation, `emconfigure ./configure`
I get a similar exception that ends with `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`
Note: I even get this error when I execute the command in a directory without any spaces.